# Configuration issues, cannot synchronize host xxx

Tags: vmware-esxi

We have a ESXi4 server setup and every day we get the error "configuration issues, cannot synhronize host xxx operation timed out". When that happens all the VM's on that server go unresponsive. Our only recourse is to power down the server (normal shut down just hangs during the shutdown process".

I did a search here for those key words and came up blank. Any thoughts or ideas?

I'm guessing it is a hardware issues of some sort. We are running on a Lenovo desktop model 6075AGU, duo core 2.33 e6550, 8GB RAM and ESXi is running off of a USB jump drive. We have a 2nd server on identical hardware running the same way (USB drive) and that server has zero issues.

Thanks....

Comment: How many VMs? Hard drives pegged? Whats your disk hardware?  I sure hope you are not running these desktops with ESXi in production...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a server, it's a desktop running server software, I'm not surprised you're having problems - have you come across VMWare's [HCL](http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work for ESXi because I've never used that version but I have a similar problem with one host in our cluster.  The fix I use so I don't have to restart the host is to get into the command line and use the following command to restart the service that connects to the virtual center.

service mgmt-vmware restart

Like I said I'm not sure this will work for you but it's worth a try.  I'm currently pursuing a better solution but have yet to find one.